# Sending information back to ios from rails api

Tags: ios, ruby-on-rails, afnetworking

I am very new to rails so sorry if this is a very obvious question. I have an ios app using a rest api. I am having no trouble posting and retrieving information to rails using AFNetworking. My problem is that when I create a certain object, I would like rails to send back the id for the object I just created. If this requires a simple answer that would be great, but if not, a tutorial or another suggestions would be great. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use i believe render and using json as the key

> render(:json =>stuff, [callback =>hash] ) Renders stuff as json,
>   forcing the content type to be application/json. Spec- ifying
>   :callback will cause the result to be wrapped in a call to the named
>   callback function.

You can read further here http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/Base/render#1490-Rendering-JSONP

Comment: So how would you call this from the ios client

Comment: this is rails code , in iOS you can just call the action method under which you have defined it in rails(url) as a POST method with parameters

Comment: So I understand the how to do the POST to create the object, but does that return the object_id in the ios client?

Comment: yes, it does the part *forcing the content type to be application/json.* is the one that will sent a response back to the request which AFNetworking will parse